# Multiprocessing/Multithreading - does not improve speed - Python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm new in multiprocessing/multithreading module and I'm trying to check whether it can improve the speed of my program. The problem is that it returns unexpected values. I tried also `threading.Thread` instead of `multiprocessing.Process` and the same problem occurred - it run slower than without using another thread.

In this example I used multiprocessing module, but it is almost the same when I tried multithreading (differencies are in comments)
Here is the code which prints time when 2 functions are running sequential and time when these functions are running parallel:

```
import time
from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing import Process
import MyFile

    class PerformanceTesting:

        def __init__(self):
            self.clss = MyFile.MyClass('A')
            self.p1 = Process(target=self.f1) # I've tried also t1 = Thread(target=f1)
            self.p2 = Process(target=self.f2) # I've tried also t2 = Thread(target=f2)

        def f1(self):
            results = self.clss.doSomething(arg,arg)
            print results

        def f2(self):
            results = self.clss.doSomething(arg,arg)
            print results

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        perf = PerformanceTesting()

        # ATTEMPT USING MULTIPROCESSING
        start = time.time()
        perf.p1.start()
        perf.f2()
        perf.p1.join()
        print time.time()-start

        # ATTEMPT WITHOUT USING MULTIPROCESSING
        start = time.time()
        perf.f1()
        perf.f2()
        print time.time()-start
```

Could you tell me whether is possible to improve the speed of this example?
What I do wrong?

I have an idea: Isn't it because dividing into more processes or threads takes a few seconds so it can't help in situations when result has to be returned in one second?

Comment: What does the `doSomething()` method do?  Is it mostly I/O (e.g. reading and writing files, network, etc.) or CPU (number crunching, data manipulation, etc.)?  Under Python, threads are better at the former and processes at the latter.

Comment: @Kevin CPU (manipulation with strings), is there a difference?  Thanks

Comment: More important than what does `doSomething()` do, is how long does it take to run? If the function is finishing in a very short amount of time, introducing sub-processes probably isn't going to make a noticeable difference, and might end up being slower.

Comment: @user3371056 In Python, threads can't speed up CPU-bound operations, because the Global Interpreter Lock prevents more than one thread from running at a time.

Comment: @dano Some CPU-bound operations can be sped up by using threads. Anything that isn't implemented in pure python, and releases the global interpreter lock can benefit from being multi-threaded. `numpy` is probably the biggest and best example of code can be sped up in a multi-threaded environment.

Comment: @Dunes Thanks, It is possible to use my code but compile it as

Comment: No. You would need to write your module in C, which is a tricky process subject to many types of errors. Like dano said. By far the most important thing is what `doSomething()` does. `multiprocessing` also incurs significant overhead in creating a new process and sending arguments to the process and receiving return values from the process. The former is especially true on Windows where child processes must be "spawned" rather than "forked". A "forked" process is essentially a copy, and is much quicker to produce than a "spawned" process.

Comment: @Dunes Sorry for my unfinished question above, I didn't know that it had been sent. Anyway, I heard that (for example) Jython stands on JVM which is not limited by GIL and that Jython has the same syntax as Python (I'm not an expert, just heard, don't know if there are mutual modules). So I though that if I Install Jython, copy my code somewhere which is able to compile Jython code... it would run faster... just thinking.. What do you think?

Comment: You could certainly try that. There's also IronPython which runs on the C# VM. Be aware that Jython and IronPython do not support Python 3.x, and you will be unable to use any non-pure Python modules (such as numpy and scipy).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that look off to me here, at least for what you're trying to do:

```
perf.p1.start()
perf.f2()
perf.p1.join()
```

This starts the process `p1`, then executes `f2`, but then waits for p1 to complete through `p1.join()`. This seems to defeat the purpose of multiprocessing - from your post I assume you think that running a process on a separate thread makes it go faster - unfortunately, unless you physically get a better CPU, this will never be the case.

The point of multiprocessing is that your code can trigger a thread's `start` function and then forget about it until it finishes, getting on with other things in the mean time. What's important there is that unless you start dividing up your code into many different parts that run in parallel so they can finish very quickly on an individual basis, you will never see a speed increase in one thread in particular compared to the others while executing the same code.

what you could do in this case is:

```
perf.p1.start()
perf.p2.start()
... do some more code, after which something happens when these two finish.
```

This will go straight through to the next part of the code without waiting for your functions to finish, which will stop the functions from blocking the main thread. You will have to implement  a signal/slot system to actually trigger an action when they do complete though.

Hope this helps.